# How can I automatically open the first file in a folder using C++?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

How can I automatically open and read the content of a file within a given directory from a C++ application without knowing the file's name?

For example (a rough description of the program):

```
#include iomanip      
#include dirent.h     
#include fstream   
#include iostream   
#include stdlib.h

using namespace std;

int main()              
{
      DIR* dir;                                                   
      struct dirent* entry;                                          
      dir=opendir("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\links\\");        
      printf("Directory contents: ");                             

      for(int i=0; i<3; i++)                                      
      {

           entry=readdir(dir);                                     
           printf("%s\n",entry->d_name);                           
      }
      return 0;
}
```

This will print the name of the first file in that directory. My problem is how to read that particular file's content and save it in a .txt document. Can `ifstream` do that? (Sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: Your English isn't as bad as you think. I've begun to notice a pattern that those who are careful enough to apologize for their language skills are the same ones who are careful enough that what they ask makes sense in the first place.

Comment: What's "the first file"? It obviously depends on the sorting order. You may wish to look at [the boost::filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm), though. I am not aware of any standard and cross-platform to do it.

Comment: What i meant was that you have a folder that contains maybe thousands of files. And I'm trying to write a program using only C++ to read the files in that folder one by one and copy its content to a .txt document then save it. These process will be done automatically by the program. So what the user has to do is just execute the program.

Comment: Oh, and I'm using Code::Blocks C++ on Windows Vista by the way.

Answer (score 5):

this should do it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

void show_files( const path & directory, bool recurse_into_subdirs = true )
{
  if( exists( directory ) )
  {
    directory_iterator end ;
    for( directory_iterator iter(directory) ; iter != end ; ++iter )
      if ( is_directory( *iter ) )
    {
      cout << iter->native_directory_string() << " (directory)\n" ;
      if( recurse_into_subdirs ) show_files(*iter) ;
    }
    else
      cout << iter->native_file_string() << " (file)\n" ;
    copyfiles(iter->native_file_string());
  }
}

void copyfiles(string s)
{
  ifstream inFile;

  inFile.open(s);

  if (!inFile.is_open()) 
  {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    exit(1); // terminate with error
  }
    //Display contents
  string line = "";

    //Getline to loop through all lines in file
  while(getline(inFile,line))
  {
    cout<<line<<endl; // line buffers for every line
        //here add your code to store this content in any file you want.
  }

  inFile.close();
}
int main()
{
  show_files( "/usr/share/doc/bind9" ) ;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows you can use the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) in the Windows API. Here is a short example:

```
HANDLE myHandle;
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
myHandle = FindFirstFile("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\links\\*", &findData);
do {
    if (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
        cout << "Directoryname is " << findData.cFileName << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Filename is " << findData.cFileName << endl;
    }
} while (FindNextFile(myHandle, &findData));
```

Otherwise I'd go with [ayushs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895317/how-can-i-automatically-open-the-first-file-in-a-folder-using-c/4895411#4895411), Boost works for unix systems as well

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works. I have another problem. After the program opens and reads the file, I'm unable to move the file from one directory to another using system("move OldDirectory NewDirectory"). Because I don't have the name of the file that I'm going to move. Is there any way that I can use the findData.cFileName like you mention in the code to move my file to a new location but maintaining the same file name? Sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: the `cFileName` isn't the absolute path to the file, so you would have to set the directory where the file is located to your [working directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530(VS.85).aspx), or concat the directory with the filename and use that as `OldDirectory`. Also, instead of using system  and want to continue using Windows API, check out [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239(VS.85).aspx)