# opening a file in random named folder using c/c++

Tags: c++, windows, file

I'm trying to code a program where it opens and reads a file automatically. But the problem is the file is stored in a folder which name is unknown. I only know where the folder is located and the file's name. How to get to that file's path in char* ?

Edit: example: `d:\files\<random folder>\data.txt`

I don't know the name of random folder but I know that it exists in `d:\files`

Comment: Do you know how to list all folders in d:\files?

Comment: What happens when two directories have the same file?

Comment: There is currently no C++ way to iterate over files in a given directory (which is, of course, a shame and terrible legacy). You'd have to use third-party lib like boost.

Comment: Let's assume whomever made the files folder made sure that there was no file having the same names in different folders.

Comment: @dunkyp No. I don't know.

Comment: Try having a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: I highly reccommed using `/` as your directory separator.  The '\' is an escape character and some are control characters such as `\t`, `\f`, and `\b` (tab, formfeed and backspace).

Comment: The random folder is the only folder in that directory

Comment: you can probably use the solutions from here to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c

Comment: or from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895317/how-can-i-automatically-open-the-first-file-in-a-folder-using-c?rq=1

Comment: Some compilers (like GCC 5) have experimental support for the `<filesystem>` TS (Technical Specification): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs

Comment: POSIX [provides a **f**ile **t**ree **w**alk function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftw.html):  `ftw()`.  You can use it to iterate over all entries in or under a specific directory, thus looking for your file.  You may or may not have access to it via something like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: since this is Windows, I highly recommend *against* using forward slash as a directory separator.  Windows accepts it in certain contexts, but not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is tagged `windows`, you might as well use the Windows API functions:

- [FindFirstFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx)
- [FindNextFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx)

to enumerate and loop through all the files in a given directory.

To check for a directory, look at `dwFileAttributes` contained in the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure (filled by the calls to `Find...File()`). But make sure to skip `.` and `..` directories. If needed, this can be done recursively.

You can check the links for some examples, or see [Listing the Files in a Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200.aspx).

In case you are using MFC, you can use [CFileFind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618.aspx) (which is a wrapper around the API functions):

```
CFileFind finder;
BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(_T("*.*"));
while (bWorking)
{
   bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
   TRACE(_T("%s\n"), (LPCTSTR)finder.GetFileName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I implemented this using the new, experimental `<filesystem>` [FS Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) supported by `GCC 5`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

// for readability
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    if(!argv[1])
    {
        std::cerr << "require 2 parameters, search directory and filename\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fs::path search_dir = argv[1];

    if(!fs::is_directory(search_dir))
    {
        std::cerr << "First parameter must be a directory: " << search_dir << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(!argv[2])
    {
        std::cerr << "Expected filename to search for\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // file to search for
    fs::path file_name = argv[2];

    const fs::directory_iterator dir_end; // directory end sentinel

    // used to iterate through each subdirectory of search_dir
    fs::directory_iterator dir_iter(search_dir);

    for(; dir_iter != dir_end; ++dir_iter)
    {
        // skip non directories
        if(!fs::is_directory(dir_iter->path()))
            continue;

        // check directory for file

        // iterate through files in this subdirectory dir_iter->path()
        auto file_iter = fs::directory_iterator(dir_iter->path());

        for(; file_iter != dir_end; ++file_iter)
        {
            // ignore directories and wrong filenames
            if(fs::is_directory(file_iter->path())
            || file_iter->path().filename() != file_name)
                continue;

            // Ok we found it (the first one)
            std::cout << "path: " << file_iter->path().string() << '\n';
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    // Not found
    std::cout << file_name << " was not found in " << search_dir.string() << '\n';

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The idea is: list the directories under `d:\files` and try to open 
the file in each directory.

There isn't (yet) a standard C++ way of getting all the existing files/directories. A crude but easy way of doing this would be

```
system("dir d:\\files /b /ad > tmpfile");
```

This lists all directories (`/ad`), redirected to a temporary file. Then open the file:

```
std::ifstream list("tmpfile");
```

And read it:

```
std::string dirname;
std::string filename;
while (std::getline(list, dirname))
{
    filename = "d:\\files\\" + dirname + "\\data.txt";
    if ( ... file exists ... )
        break;
}
```

I call this method crude because it has problems that are hard/impossible to fix:

- It overwrites a potentially useful file
- It doesn't work if current directory is read-only
- It will only work in Windows

It might be possible to use [`_popen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) and `fgets` instead of redirecting to file.

Comment: can i store the file in some other directory? in case that folder is read-only

Comment: Yes. Also, if you use `_popen`, there is no need for a temp-file.